# rowsums of letter factor

Tags: r

I am trying to use `rowSums` to count the number of instances a nucleotide is present within a set of samples.

The size of my df is 37,000,000 rows x 52 columns.

A short example:

```
Chromosome,Position,Allele1,Allele2,Sample1,Sample2,Sample3,Sample4
1,1,T,A,T,T,T,A
```

I would like to create a new column with the number of times the value of column `Allele1` was observed in that row, excluding columns `Allele1` and `Allele2`.

I have tried the following, but to no success:

```
df$Allele1_counts <- rowSums(df[-4] == df$Allele1)
```

It should be noted that `Allele1` and `Allele2` are factors with 4 possible levels (ACGT), and each `Sample` is factor with 5 possible levels (ACGTN), where N is the absence of a nucleotide read.

The expected output in the above example would have a 3 under `Allele1_counts` and a 1 under `Allele2_counts`.

Comment: I guess you need `rowSums(df1[-(1:4)] == df1$Allele1)`